# In memory copy during execution

Tags: assembly, embedded-linux, elf, qemu, linker-scripts

I am trying a different approach with code exchange during program execution. Using QEMU as simulation with a  VersatilePB board of ARM926EJ-S core. I found a function that uses the UART to print the passed string. In the main, there are 3 function calls yet these functions are implemented in different files for elaboration, every function definition is in its own file. the function definition is nothing more than calling `print_uart0()` with a different string to print. Hence the use of the keyword `extern` so that during linking, the functions will be able to find the `print_uart0()` definition.

```
void extern print_uart0(const char *s) {
while(*s != '\0') { /* Loop until end of string */
*UART0DR = (unsigned int)(*s); /* Transmit char */
s++; /* Next char */
 }
}
void main() {
 function_1();
 function_2();
 function_3();
 function_1();
 function_1();
}
```

What I want to do is, for example, to exchange the `.text` section of `function_3()` with the `.text` section of `function_1()` if I have an interrupt signal or change the status of GPIO
so basically the desired output should change from

```
"print from function 1"
"print from function 2"
"print from function 3"
"print from function 1"
"print from function 1"
```

it should be like

```
"print from function 1"
"print from function 2"
"print from function 3"
---------interrupt/code exchange event occurs here ----------
"print from function 3"
"print from function 3"
```

The purpose is to keep the main with its function calls the same as it is but to exchange the instructions itself to execute different ones. I have found a similar post that discusses a similar situation
[in-memory copying in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258300/in-memory-copying-in-assembly) but the target architecture is x86 so if someone could guide me for alternative ARM instructions or a better approach then that would be great.

I have good knowledge of elf file and I can write my own linker script to place the `.text` section of each function in a different memory address

Comment: use pointer to function instead of replacing body of functions. Based on your example it's an easier way around. And BTW you still could use common 'memcpy' to copy function body, it does not need to be an assembler implemented function. But such copying would require to know function size which normally are done via linker script and proper handling of instruction cache after copying body of functions.

Comment: Are you supposed to be copying around whole functions, or are you supposed to look for the one or two instructions inside the function that put the address of a string in a register, and update just that?  Apparently you're doing some kind of exercise, based on the way you phrase it. In real life (e.g. in the Linux kernel), if you were going to set up some code for runtime modification (instead of func pointers), it would normally be in a more controlled way, where you know what instruction(s) you're going to be changing.  (e.g. making `strex` into a plain `str` if an atomic RMW isn't needed.)

Comment: And you'd only want to modify machine code if the change happens *vastly* less frequently than the code executes, and the slowdown from using function pointers instead of a direct call would actually be a problem.  (You still need to avoid having the function inlined, so there's still a call).  e.g. like Linux, patching out x86 `lock` prefixes if booted on a uniprocessor machine, or similar tricks.  If you wanted the same real-world behaviour as this, you'd be loading a `volatile char*` or one of 3, and change what it points at from an interrupt handler.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to mess with functions body copying around.
Use function pointer to call right function

```
void print1()
{
    printf("Function1\n");
}

void print2()
{
    printf("Function2\n");
}

void (*fptr)();// declare function pointer

int main()
{
    fptr = print1; // assign function pointer to 'print1' function
    fptr();        // call 'print1()' by pointer

    fptr = print2; // <-- assign pointer to another function inside interrupt routine

    fptr();        // would call 'print2()'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand but the task is about dynamic functions allocation, having totally separated functions in different files, compile and execute specific ones with an option to exchange others during runtime so function pointers are not an option for me

Comment: what do you mean by "compile and execute specific ones" ? runtime compilation of any random code ?

Comment: as I explained earlier, I have an application that has specific functions, the target is not to change functions calls order, the goal is to keep the main as it is, and depending on the interrupt signal then certain functions instructions will be placed instead of the original ones

Comment: `int main() { fptr(); fptr(); fptr(); }`. `main()` is same but `fptr` could be assigned to different function. So that's calling different functions without changing anything else

Comment: @PeterCordes I am supposed to copy all the instructions of function_3 to be replaced instead of instructions of function_1, assuming that all the functions have the same signature. so flow should be function un registration, exchange code then registration

Comment: @AmrMahmoud: I moved my comments to under the question, since they're not really a reply to this answer.  (Although I was initially replying to your comments here.)